How to put Java code in JSP file with SpringBoot?
I got this error after I put this code on my index.jsp file
The code :
<body>

    <h1>Student</h1>
    <p>
        Status Connection : ${connStatus == "Connected" ? "Connected" : "Disconnected"} ${connMessage}
    </p>

the error I've got :
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Apr 18 03:34:46 WIB 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.apache.jsp.web_002dtpl.views.index_jsp

I want to check connection to database from my controller file, so I try send it to the JSP file, this is the code :
    private String connStatus = "Disconnected";
    private String connMessage = "";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            
            connStatus = "Connected";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            connMessage = e.getMessage();
        }

        model.addAttribute("connStatus", connStatus);
        model.addAttribute("connMessage", connMessage);

        return "index";
    }

I don't know what's the right way bcs this is my first time to use springboot, any thought?

you need add this code in your jsp file


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You need to use right syntax of JSP EL expression:
Status Connection : ${connStatus == 'Connected' ? 'Connected' : 'Disconnected'} ${connMessage}


You can learn Expression Language from the Java Tutorial.
